# Keyboard Event on Alert with Sweet alert library

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I am uisng Sweet alert library

Using this library, I have found weird behavior; Pressing keyboard's spacebar selects 'confirm' in alert. However, after pressing 'cancel', 'confirm' using spacebar event on later attempt does not work.
(With alert,  pressing spacebar always confirms option/message)

Comment: so , what issue you facing ? or what you want exactly ?

Comment: @Viplock
So what I want to do is regardless of pressing cancel button previously, spacebar event always confirms the option of the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original sweet alert plugin is unsupported, I suggest you using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) plugin.

Migration is simple, here's the migration guide: [Migration from SweetAlert to SweetAlert2](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2)

---

SweetAlert2 focuses the confirm button every time the user opens a pop-up.

In addition, you will be able to customize that behavior by using `focusCancel` and `allowEnterKey` parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response

Answer (score 1):

It work that way because ,it check when the popup is opened where the focus is set , if you will press `tab button` and then press `space bar` it will perform the cancel action. So here `Conform` button is primary button and its gonna be the button in focus by default.

And one more thing , its not only `space` button `Enter` also do the same, the difference is just that on `space bar` its a `keyup` event and on `Enter button` its a `keyPress` event.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand the explanation. So how can I always make the confirm button as default focus everytime I open that pop-up with this library(Sweet alert)?

Comment: sweet alert 2 will be the best solution for you. it will always go for confirm button as default. Hope it will help. https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/

Comment: Thanks for your kind response